# what is better in CSS-file: many statements or long statements?

Tags: html, css

Just wondering... I am using a long css file. About 1100 lines for a SAAS-application build in mostly tables (nested very deep). I can't change the HTML. The website has various styles. There is one basic stylesheet with the main style. For somne of the users there is an overruling style sheet. This contains only the changes on the main style.

With this in mind, should i go for

```
.class_x{background-color:#123456;}
.class_y{background-color:#123456;}
.class_z{background-color:#123456;}
.class_p{background-color:#123456;}
```

or this:

```
.class_x, .class_y, .class_z, .class_p{background-color:#123456;}
```

Is one of these faster? Better in any way?

Comment: I've always been taught that the latter is more efficient. Couldn't tell you why, though.

Comment: If you want to change the color, do you want to make four edits, or one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer to use second way (group).

Similar styles can be grouped together to reduce code lines, avoid repetition and help in the semantics of your CSS.

You can group items by their similar proprierties, like in this case:

```
.class_x, .class_y, .class_z, .class_p{font-color: white}

.class_x{background-color:#333;}
.class_y{background-color:#111;}
.class_z{background-color:#999;}
.class_p{background-color:#666;}
```

Of course, if you need to change just one of the classes, remove it from the group and create it separated, like:

```
.class_x, .class_y, .class_z{background-color:#123456;}
.class_p{background-color:#999999;}
```

Take a look in this page (tip #7 talks about it): http://www.queness.com/post/588/15-ways-to-optimize-css-and-reduce-css-file-size

Comment: Thank you @dimas-pante! Interesting article btw :-)